# Chrome mobile HTML5 audio play button control is not working

Tags: android, html, angularjs, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have trouble making my audio tag working on mobile device (works fine on desktop or iPad).

I have tried to embedded my audio URL in an iframe and it work fine.
Without iframe, autoplay and seek slider works but play/stop, mute buttons don't work at all.

My code looks like this:

```
<iframe 
  ng-if="question.audioId" 
  ng-src="{{$ctrl.API.services + '/api/asset/' + question.audioId | trustUrl}}" 
  controls>
</iframe>

<audio 
  ng-if="question.audioId" 
  ng-src="{{$ctrl.API.services + '/api/asset/' + question.audioId | trustUrl}}" 
  controls 
  preload="metadata">
</audio>
```

[the view looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5EZm.png)
(top: using iframe, bottom using audio tag: the yellow square is outline css)

Comment: Have the found an solution? Looks like Chrome `<audio>` bug as it works good on Firefox. `<video>` instead of `<audio>` seems to work.